# Locale fallbacks to the default value after Facebook login using HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I have a problem, that when I switch the language on my site, and I do a Facebook Login using `HWIOAuthBundle`, I always get redirect to the default locale, what I set in the `config.yml`. *(in my case: "en")*

routing.yml

```
# Facebook Connect 
hwi_oauth_security:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/login
    defaults: { _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|de

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/login
    defaults: { _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|de

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/login
    defaults: { _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|de

facebook_login:
    path: /{_locale}/login/check-facebook
    defaults: { _locale: en }
requirements:
    _locale: en|de

# Site Routing #
homepage:
    path:     /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: MyPageBundle:Homepage:index, _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|de
```

oauth firewall settings in security.xml

```
 firewalls:
        main:
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: "/%locale%/login/check-facebook"
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                failure_path: fos_user_security_login
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: hwi_oauth_user_provider
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: "/%locale%"
```

After that when I open the `mysite.com/en/login/facebook`, I get successfully logged in with my facebook account and get redirect to the following link: `mysite.com/en#_=_`

But  when I open `mysite.com/de/login/facebook`, I get redirect to the same url like in the previous case. It seems that the locale doesn't get passed after the redirection and fallbacks to the default locale.

In every other case the locale works fine. For example I'm using FOSUserBundle and after login, logout or signup I get redirect with the correct locale every time.

Could someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the source of the problem. I used the `%locale%` variable in my `facebook resource_owners` which is not the same as the `_locale` variable but it is the `locale` variable in my `parameters.yml`. So I solved my problem with the following modifications:

- [I made my Locale "sticky"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html).
- I modified the value of `facebook resource_owners` to `facebook-login` route.

After that I received a `No resource owner with name 'check-facebook'` error message, but I solved it by deleting every `_locale` related things from the `facebook-login` route:

```
facebook_login:
    path: /login/check-facebook
```

I hope it will helps to others too :)